# SSRS text box value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to enter a value from textbox in SSRS, but its not giving the value from that textbox. Instead it is showing value from another textbox.

Example: The below is my table structure with groups. When I try to use Week1 value, it displays Week2.

(Note: ReportItems!ID.value is to dipslay Week1 textbox)

[image]

Expr-

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to group (pivot) by week?

Comment: Just to be clear: the name of the `[Sum(Net)]` textbox located under `Week1` is `ID`?

Comment: Hi nicky, yes it is!

Comment: any update on this ?